# Jquery cycle advance pager - how to call different thumbnail imagesource?

Tags: jquery, thumbnails, cycle, pager, imagesource

I am using the following markup to set up my jquery cycle slideshow. However, I would like to figure out how to implement thumbnails with a different image src. If my enlarged image src is image-file-name.jpg, how can I call for thumbnails with the src th-image-file-name.jpg?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#s2').cycle({ 
fx:     'fade', 
speed:  'slow', 
timeout: 0, 
next:   '#next', 
prev:   '#prev', 
pager:  '#thumbs',
after: onAfter,

// callback fn that creates a thumbnail to use as pager anchor 
pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + jQuery(slide).find('img').attr('src') + '" width="140" height="140" /></a></li>'; }

 });


 function onAfter(curr, next, opts, fwd) {
 var index = opts.currSlide;
 //$('#prev')[index == 0 ? 'hide' : 'show']();
 //$('#next')[index == opts.slideCount - 1 ? 'hide' : 'show']();
//get the height of the current slide
var $ht = $(this).height();
//set the container's height to that of the current slide
$(this).parent().animate({height: $ht});
}
});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this tutorial will help you achieve what you're looking for: [Tutorial](http://www.drselkirk.com/sneazy-blog/2011/6/22/jquery-cycle-demo-w-custom-thumbnail-navigation-and-live-tex.html)

Here is a demo: [Demo](http://www.drselkirk.com/storage/blog/Cycle-Custom-Navigation/index.html)